# How do projective indecomposable bimodules look like?

Tags: abstract-algebra, reference-request, representation-theory, projective-module, bimodules

I have been trying (without much success) to find a reference for learning about projective indecomposable $A$-$A$-bimodules: here $A$ denotes a finite-dimensional algebra over a field $K$.

I think I understand the picture when $A$ is basic and the underlying field is algebraically closed: using Lemma 5.3.8 and Corollary 5.3.10 in [Representation theory: a homological algebra point of view](https://books.google.de/books?id=yRhMBAAAQBAJ&lpg=PA448&ots=Yd93d9JOIv&dq=Lemma%205.3.8%20zimmermann&pg=PA448#v=onepage&q=Lemma%205.3.8%20zimmermann&f=false), one concludes that the projective indecomposable bimodules must be of the form $Ae_i\otimes_K e_j A$, where $\{e_i\}_{i \in I}$ forms a complete irredundant set of primitive idempotents in $A$.

I would like to know what happens more generally, for instance, if $A$ is not necessarily basic and/or $K$ is not so nice.